# Static в методах

Tags: java

Такая ошибка:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile(); // здесь выдаётся ошибка, но если указать ниже в методе public STATIC void readFile() то ошибка уходит.
    }

    public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("sdsd");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка, как я понял в том, что метод не статический передаю в статический метод

```
Public static void main(String[] args)
```

Правильно ли я мыслю или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статический метод вызывается у класса, не статический метод вызывается у объекта.

Вам надо либо сделать `readFile()` статическим, либо в методе `main()` создать объект и у него вызвать метод `readFile()`:

```
Test test = new Test();    
test.readFile();
```

Answer (score 6):

Дело не в том, что вы передаете нестатический метод в статический.
Дело в том, что для использования нестатического метода необходимо использовать его на экземпляре класса. **Статические** же **методы можно вызывать без экземпляра класса**.
Посмотрите на эти примеры:

```
public class AnotherClass {

static AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass(); //здесь мы создаем статическую переменную, иначе компилятор будет ругаться

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnotherClass b = new AnotherClass(); //здесь использование static не обязательно, так как переменная создается внутри метода

    a.readFile();
    b.readFile(); // оба варианта возможны
}

public void readFile() {
    try {
        File file = new File("sdsd");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
} // если не использовать конструкцию try{} catch{}, то компилятор будет ругаться на неотловленное исключение. Ключевое слово throws же говорит о том, что внутри метода вручную бросается какое-то исключение с помощью throw, что у вас не происходит.
```

}